# Hover Div and Table Rows at Same time

Tags: html, css

What are the possible ways of making a hover effect on a particular div and its corresponding table row.

Say I have 3 divs and 3 rows in a table, and I want a situation where when you hover the first div the first row in the table shows the hover effect as well, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this HTML:

```
<div class="divs">
    <div>div a</div>
    <div>div b</div>
    <div>div c</div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What you want is very simple with a few helper functions (`qsa`, `on`, and `each`):

```
var divs = qsa('.divs div');
var rows = qsa('table tr');
each(divs, function(div, i) {
    on(div, 'mouseover', function() {
        rows[i].classList.add('hover');
    });
    on(div, 'mouseout', function() {
        rows[i].classList.remove('hover');
    });
});



/* helpers
**************************************/

// Get elements by CSS selector:
function qsa(selector, scope) {
    return (scope || document).querySelectorAll(selector);
}

// Add event listeners:
function on(target, type, callback, useCapture) {
    target.addEventListener(type, callback, !!useCapture);
}

// Loop through collections:
function each(arr, fn, scope) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        fn.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/bukinuhopa/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Wow. Awesome!!! But I have problems integrating it on my wordpress site. It doesnt work

Comment: @OtoObong Make sure the selectors on lines 1 and 2 of the JS match your element structure and also the selectors in the css. Without seeing your new problem in detail, I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and if hover is run on element you can do the same on the rest of divs in row.